# Strange String Format for Date

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

Java application gets a stream of JSON messages, 
within those, the String fields, that represent some date are formatted like \"2019-01-01+01:00\".

It looks like a normal date, followed by the timezone-offset, this guess of mine has been confirmed on the producer side.

**Problem:**
Even though I still do not really get the logic behind it, I have to parse it in my Java App. 
The simplest approach would be to split that string on the '+' character and just parse the date part with some pattern in LocalDate.

But out of curiosity, maybe there is some Date format in Java I do not know of, which could allow for this strange string format?

Comment: Ok, for now, am parsing it as follows:                                                                        `java.util.Date dateWithOffset = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddXXX").parse(dateStr);`

Comment: Don't use `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those are ancient and badly written classes. Not `Calendar`, either. Only use `java.time` classes.

Comment: Dates with offsets (but without time) are problematic logically because they don't say *when* on that date the offset applied.  The only spec I'm aware of that defines them is in the W3C XML Schema Definition, where the [`xsd:date`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#date) object has an optional `timezoneOffset`.  A common interpretation of that spec is that the offset applies only to the first moment of that date (usually `00:00`).  Thus, if a date has a transition in offset (such as the start or end of DST, or a change in standard time), that information is not represented.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Interesting source for this idea of "date with offset". I have to point out a flaw with their logic: Representing a locality’s start of a day in the future cannot be done with merely an offset. The offset used in defining the start of the day can change in a zone’s evolving rules.

Comment: Hi @MattJohnson-Pint, I have got the confirmation from publisher that the XSD convertion is the source of data. Great hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is. [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE). I agree that it’s weird, and I don’t know what use you should have of the offset. But you can parse into a `LocalDate` using the formatter:

```
    String stringFromJson = "2019-01-01+01:00";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(stringFromJson, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE);
    System.out.println(date);
```

Output:

> 2019-01-01

**Splitting at the `+` (plus sign) will not always work.** A date with an offset may also come with a negative offset, for example `-04:00`, and with offset `Z` (for zero, that is, UTC). Of course you could write code to handle each of those situations manually, but it’s better to use the built-in formatter.

**Don’t use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`.** Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the latter in particular notoriously troublesome. Use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: By the way, I thought perhaps this senseless idea of "date with offset" may have come from the SQL standard which has contained a few such oddities over the years. I searched through a draft of SQL:2011. While I do find explicit references to the also senseless `TIME WITH TIME ZONE`, I find no explicit mention of `DATE WITH TIME ZONE` nor `WITHOUT`.

Comment: I am under the impression that it comes from XML, @BasilBourque. See for example [XSD Date and Time Data Types](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_dtypes_date.asp).

Comment: @Ole V.V. Thanks, yes I have got the confirmation that the source of that is the data comming from XSD. You are also right, about the usage of the JDK 8 CLasses, but sometimes in a hurry I am still reluctant to use the oldies :) But most importantly, i now know that there is a standard format for it ISO_OFFSET_DATE, therefore thanks for your effors it is always cool to learn something new!